# How to print small images in high resolution

Tags: vector, printing, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to print images that are roughly .5 inch x .5 inch in size (small enough to fit on a fingernail) but they come out very pixelated (on the computer screen they look fine). They end up looking like retro 8bit images (https://i.stack.imgur.com/42w5M.jpg) which looks cool, but not my desired output.

I've seen others who print out nail decals and their images look very clear - near perfect. Is this just a matter of them having a better printer, or is there something i'm missing to do in process? Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I assume these are raster images. If so, you need higher resolution images. With sufficiently high resolution, they will print out looking good. The other alternative is to convert them to vector images.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resolution of your file? It is likely that they are too small or the resolution is too low. Bigger images scaled down will always be your friend over small images scaled up.